# Spring Boot 2 with Netflix Zuul not working?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a very simple Zuul app that I'm trying to run, just to get things off the ground, with no filters or anything fancy like that.  I'm just trying to get a simple pass-through running for a service that I'm wanting to test. However, it doesn't seem as though the Zuul mappings or routes are being created, and I'm just getting 404's for all of my requests.

For my zuul edge server, here's my setup :

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gzuul</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>gzuul</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 8084
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    mappings:
      enabled: true
    routes:
      enabled: true
zuul:
  routes:
    invoicing:
      path: /invoicing/**
      url: [url that I know works]/invoicing
```

And my "main" class :

```
package com.example.gzuul;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class GzuulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GzuulApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So, yeah, really simple setup overall.

However, whenever I try to access the a url like localhost:8084/invoicing/[some stuff to pass through] I get the following errors :

```
2018-09-17 11:55:19.625 DEBUG 34902 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /invoicing/v1/invoice/7900007809
2018-09-17 11:55:19.629 DEBUG 34902 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/invoicing/v1/invoice/7900007809]
2018-09-17 11:55:19.629 DEBUG 34902 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /invoicing/v1/invoice/7900007809
2018-09-17 11:55:19.629 DEBUG 34902 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/invoicing/v1/invoice/7900007809]
```

Also, trying to access /actuator/routes brings back a 404 as well.

Any help would be appreciated, and more info can be provided if the above is not enough.

Comment: I got that exact error when I didn't have `@EnableZuulProxy`. Otherwise an identical app works fine for me. Can you share a downloadable sample? Actuator won't work since it isn't a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It is stranger that Zuul's behavior in your app, did you missing some config(such as zuul.prefix server.prefix...) which may from other location?

See your config: 

`zuul:
  routes:
    invoicing:
      path: /invoicing/**
      url: [url that I know works]/invoicing`

it means all invoke from `zuul-server/invoicing/**` should be route to `[back-server-url]/invoicing/**`, so in your output `[zuul-server]/invoicing/v1/invoice/7900007809` should route to `[back-server-url]/invoicing/v1/invoice/7900007809` but with `not find handler method`, is that means `[back-server-url]/invoicing/v1/invoice/7900007809` is not available?

btw 1. you can check output during application starting and it should print url mapping for zuul and actuator setting and it is useful for debug same questions. 2. `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul` actually has `Ribbon` `Hystrix` and `Actuator` dependencies as default, `actuator` should work and you can check `/actuator/health`

Comment: Hey @Se ven, thanks for the comment. Seems it was more to do with Zuul not actually being fully present due to some bad maven jars in my local repo cache. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, I found the answer. For some reason my MVN build had downloaded a bogus set of Zuul jars, that upon doing a 'clean' were giving me some bad LOC header errors.  Wiped my local maven repo cache and built again and now things are working correctly.